# How to count the HTTP request and response packet on dedicate URL on AWS cloudfront

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse, wireshark, amazon-cloudfront, packet-capture

A few days ago we migrate our one of web server to AWS cloudfront, we want to calculate how many request and response packet from client when they open the web server URL since AWS will count number of request and response packet, is it Wireshark can do this work and how to do it? kindly advise

Comment: Why do you think AWS will count the number of packets?

Comment: if not, any alternative way to do it??